# AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Tags: python, file, attributes, generator

I'm trying to go through this file that I've created and only extract the ages of the people in the file. then take the average of the ages and print it out. I'm trying to iterate through the lines in the file and it says that the generator object has no attribute. I'm using python 3 and I commented out some code I was using before so I don't have to worry about it. I don't know if I should use the commented code either but I'm just scared of losing all the ideas I've gotten this far. How do I get those ages in my loop if I can't iterate through?

```js
f = open('myfile.txt','w')
f.write('Name, Age, Gender, Profession\n')
f.write('Harry, 23, Male, Software Engineer\n')
f.write('Sam, 25, Male, Lawyer\n')
f.write('Lisa, 29, Female, Computer Scientist\n')
f.write('Mary, 22, Female, Doctor\n')
f.close()
# print(readFile.read())
# readFile = open("myfile.txt")

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:


    for line in file:
        values = (line.split(', ') for line in file)
        if values.isdigit[1] == True:
            numbers = 0
            numbers += values

    average = numbers % 4
    print(average)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
f = open('myfile.txt','w')
f.write('Name, Age, Gender, Profession\n')
f.write('Harry, 23, Male, Software Engineer\n')
f.write('Sam, 25, Male, Lawyer\n')
f.write('Lisa, 29, Female, Computer Scientist\n')
f.write('Mary, 22, Female, Doctor\n')
f.close()

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    numbers = 0
    for line in file:
        values = line.split(', ')
        if values[1].isdigit() == True:
            numbers += int(values[1])

    average = numbers / 4
    print(average) # 24.75
```

There are several points that can be improved:

1. `values = (line.split(', ') for line in file)` assignes a generator (mind the seemingly innocent parenthesis) to `values`, and a generator does not have `isdigit`. You are already using a `for` loop, so you don't need a generator (actually you shouldn't).
2. In the corrected code, `values` now is a list of strings. So you need to use `values[1]` to access an item of the list, and *then* apply `isdigit`.
3. You are resetting `numbers` in each iteration. Initiate the variable *before* the loop.
4. `values[1]` is a string, so in order to add this to `numbers`, you need `int`.
5. `%` is the modulus operator. Use `/` for (real) division.
6. Using a hard-coded number (in this case, dividing something by a *specific* number `4`) is not a best option. You might want an alternative way to get the number of records.